# How to autorun a ruby script in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, upstart, ruby

How hard can it possibly be to run a ruby script on startup?!

Fairly tough apparently:

I'm using `rvm` and running ruby `2.3.0`.

`which ruby` returns `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby`
The script location is: `/home/redline/sinatra-aggregator/server.rb`. I've tried all sorts of `chown`s and `chmod`s on it, maybe that's got something to do with it.

Server starts. How do I make it run `sudo ruby server.rb`? Don't even need the sudo.

There's about ten million tutorials on how to do it Using upstart, rc.local or init.d and I don't know what I'm doing because not a single one worked. I even tried crontab.

Currently, my `crontab -e` looks like this:

`@reboot /home/ubuntu/start.sh`

/home/ubuntu/start.sh:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby /home/ubuntu/sinatra-aggregator/server.rb >> log.txt
```

log.txt is always empty, by the way.

I've tried similar setups with `rc.local` and `init.d`

### Edit:

I tried running the software with `nohup`, it worked out okay but here's the output of the log:

```
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 3000 for production with backup from Thin
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)


    Starting //Blueline Scraper!


Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Stopping ...
Stopping ...
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from server.rb:2:in `<main>'
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-95:~/sinatra-aggregator$
```

I bet you anything it's RVM not providing PATH somehow to the gems that I need as not only they exist on the system but are bundle install'd. Should I use `bundle exec` in my `@reboot` directive and if not how do I add $PATH before the script execution?

**EDIT:**

Tried Michael's solution, didn't work for various reasons explained in comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35758/discussion-on-question-by-dsp-099-how-to-autorun-a-ruby-script-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
cron /home/redline/sinatra-aggregator/server.rb
cron restart
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: How would it know to use ruby and not node.js or java or whatever?

Comment: `cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied`

with sudo:

`cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 938: Resource temporarily unavailable`

okay, `pkill 938` , try again:

`cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 938: Resource temporarily unavailable`

How hard is it to ruby a ruby script? Christ